# Python IDLE Alpha Vantage Module Import Error In Technical Analysis Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, alpha-vantage

I have recently attempted to retrieve financial information concerning the price of a particular stock within Python, with the integrated development environment IDLE; in order to complete this task, I am attempting to utilise a Python module known as alphavantage, a connection to the Alpha Vantage API, which I have installed via the utilisation of pip in the MacOS terminal. The instructions for the module are on the information page for it, at this web address:

https://pypi.org/project/alphavantage/

I have run the following program as referenced on the page:

```
from alphavantage.price_history import (
    AdjustedPriceHistory, get_results, PriceHistory, IntradayPriceHistory,
    filter_dividends
    )

history = AdjustedPriceHistory(period='D')
results = history.get('AAPL')
dividends = list(filter_dividends(results.records))
```

IDLE provided the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/surengrigorian/Documents/FirstExperiment.py", line 7, in <module>
    results = history.get('AAPL')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alphavantage/price_history.py", line 133, in get
    return self.get_results(ticker, response, retrieved_at)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alphavantage/price_history.py", line 136, in get_results
    updated_at, timezone, is_intraday = self.transform_meta_data(response['Meta Data'])
KeyError: 'Meta Data'
```

Would you please provide assistance concerning this matter? I am currently utilising Python 3, I have definitively installed the module and I possess an individual file in which I am running this program. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: https://github.com/portfoliome/alphavantage/issues/14

this looks similar to your issue

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Did you end up creating an environment variable? ALPHA_VANTAGE_API_KEY

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your assistance.